# Parse int to double VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parsing

I have a computed function in VueJS which calculates the sum of an array I got. However, it only returns Int numbers rounded to nearest number, even though I parseFloat. Can anyone help me out on this one?

```
data: {
        
        courses: [{Course: "A", Hours: "02.00"}, {Course: "B", Hours: "01.00"}]
        
    },


 computed: {
        calculateAllHours: function (){
            return this.statistics.reduce((totalHours, course) => {
                let test = (totalHours) + parseInt(course.Hours)
                return parseFloat(test);
            },0.00)
        },
    },
```

The result gives me 3, but I want to have 03:00 or 03.00

Comment: Try out `let test = (totalHours) + parseFloat(course.Hours)` instead of `let test = (totalHours) + parseInt(course.Hours)`

Comment: Tried it. Was the same result.

Comment: Try `let test = parseFloat(parseFloat(totalHours) + parseFloat(course.Hours))`. I'm sure someone else can explain why, but whenever I've done this I've needed to wrap everything multiple times. I get the feeling each time the compute runs, the values are cast back to a string as they're stored in the data prop as a string but not sure.